# openshift import-images error "! error: Import failed (Unauthorized): you may not have access to the Docker image"

Tags: openshift

I need some inputs/help to bring up my container(customized) on OpenShift

```
[mag-vm@mag-vm-centos-2 ~]$ sudo docker images
REPOSITORY                               TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
mag_main                                  latest              e039447d7212        13 days ago         1.316 GB
[mag-vm@mag-vm-centos-2 ~]$ oc import-image mag_main:latest
error: no image stream named "mag_main" exists, pass --confirm to create and import
[mag-vm@mag-vm-centos-2 ~]$ oc import-image mag_main:latest --confirm
The import completed with errors.

Name:                   mag_main
Namespace:              cirrus
Created:                Less than a second ago
Labels:                 <none>
Annotations:            openshift.io/image.dockerRepositoryCheck=2017-06-07T16:24:49Z
Docker Pull Spec:       172.30.124.119:5000/cirrus/mag_main
Unique Images:          0
Tags:                   1

latest
  tagged from mag_main:latest

  ! error: Import failed (Unauthorized): you may not have access to the Docker image "mag_main:latest"
      Less than a second ago

[mag-vm@mag-vm-centos-2 ~]$
```

Could you pls help me to overcome this issue, is it something to do with the "secret" settings?

Thanks in Advance.

Also as an additional input, I am able to bring up the container for this docker image using "docker run" command
    STEP #1 : sudo docker run -t mag_main:latest /bin/bash
    STEP #2 : Once the container is up, I used "./bin/karaf" to run the services inside this docker container

Pls let me know, how can I do the same from the OpenShift.

## OpenShift Details;

```
[mag-vm@mag-vm-centos-2 ~]$ oc version
oc v1.5.1+7b451fc
kubernetes v1.5.2+43a9be4
features: Basic-Auth GSSAPI Kerberos SPNEGO

Server https://10.100.71.160:8443
openshift v1.5.1+7b451fc
kubernetes v1.5.2+43a9be4
[mag-vm@mag-vm-centos-2 ~]$
```

## Docker Details;

```
[mag-vm@mag-vm-centos-2 ~]$ sudo docker version
Client:
 Version:      1.11.2
 API version:  1.23
 Go version:   go1.5.4
 Git commit:   b9f10c9
 Built:        Wed Jun  1 21:23:11 2016
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64

Server:
 Version:      1.11.2
 API version:  1.23
 Go version:   go1.5.4
 Git commit:   b9f10c9
 Built:        Wed Jun  1 21:23:11 2016
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
[mag-vm@mag-vm-centos-2 ~]$
```

Comment: Would you normally need to login to the registry to pull the image down with ``docker pull``?

Comment: Hi Graham,

I have tried it, though I have the image in my local docker repository, docker is not able to find it. Pls let me know, if I am missing something here;

Comment: [mag_main-centos-2 ~]$ sudo docker login
Login Succeeded
[mag_main-centos-2 ~]$ sudo docker pull mag_main
Using default tag: latest
Pulling repository docker.io/library/mag_main
Error: image library/mag_main not found
[mag_main-centos-2 ~]$ sudo docker images
REPOSITORY                               TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
mag_main                                  latest              e039447d7212        2 weeks ago         1.316 GB

Comment: Is it required to do a docker pull even though I have the image in the local repository? Pls let me know.

Comment: How are you running OpenShift? When you say local repository for the image, do you mean a Docker service running on your own computer? That is not an image registry.

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton Yes you are right, I should have been more clear. I was trying to install a customized docker image and docker service is installed on my machine.